# Why does brace expansion range use two dots instead of three (ellipsis)?

Tags: bash, zsh, history, brace-expansion

I finally understood/discovered why I never got to using `bash`'s (and also `zsh`'s) brace expansion range properly: the syntax is `{1..10}` instead of what I assumed to be an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28computer_programming%29), i.e. `{1...10}`.

May I know why two dots was chosen over three dots? Usage of ellipsis in computer programming is common and well-understood as indicated by the (Wikipedia) link, which is why this piqued my curiosity.

Comment: [Apparently](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=_q7ZgTUvft0C&lpg=PA186&ots=IivYjb7R1l&dq=two%20dots%20bash%20brace%20expansion&ie=ISO-8859-1&pg=PA186#v=onepage&q=two%20dots%20bash%20brace%20expansion&f=false), it originated in [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)...

Comment: The use of `n1..n2` in programming to denote a range from *n1* to *n2*  predates Perl by quite a bit. See this [Pascal User Manual from 1970, section 6.1.2 on page 17](http://standardpascal.org/The_Programming_Language_Pascal_1970.pdf).

Comment: Hey commenters, feel free to turn your comments into answers...? :)

Comment: I have a vague recollection that some languages now even use `..` vs. `...` for including the right endpoint or not, but I may be wrong. (Ruby? Was that Ruby?)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz according to the wiki link, that will be [Rust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: @slm I'm going to have to disagree on the close reason here. History questions about how something came to be are not really opinion based. Comments have already hinted the answer is just a matter of history and in spite of the "why" in the title this _could_ be answered quite solidly.

Comment: @Caleb - good points, I'll reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(posting as community wiki instead, thanks to the contributions in the comments)

It is mentioned in the book [From Bash to Z Shell](http://www.bash2zsh.com/) (Chapter 8, Page 186, "*Generating Numbers with Braces*") that this syntax is borrowed from [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

In addition, it is also suggested that Pascal had the `..` range notation dating back as far back as *1970* (emphasis mine) ("[The Programming Language Pascal](http://standardpascal.org/The_Programming_Language_Pascal_1970.pdf)", Section 6.1.2, Page 17 of the linked PDF).

In conclusion, even the [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28computer_programming%29) from the question stated some examples where `..` is used. The *assumption* that an ellipsis is strictly defined as a sequence of three dots, as it is as a [punctuation mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), does not hold true here.